# JAVA: Receiving multicast UDP datagrams in sockets with same port and different IP multicast, in IPv4, but not in IPv6

Tags: java, sockets, ipv6, ipv4

The problem is that I have a JAVA program which open MulticastSocket with the same port, and later invokes joinGroup(Multicast address). Each socket have a differente Multicast address.

The machine has enabled ipv4 in its interfaces.

The behaviour is to receive multicast messages althoug the IP destination is different to Socket opened(the socket have same port).

On the other hand, if I enable ipv6 in the interfaces, the message with same port only are received in the socket which have IP destintation + Port.

Example:

Intefaces with ipv4:

Socket A: IP(224.0.0.3)+PORT(28200)

Socket B: IP(224.0.0.2)+PORT(28200)

I send a multicast message with PORT(28200), and IP destination(224.0.0.3).

Result: I receive the message in both Sockets.

If I change the machine interface's to ipv6, I receive the message only in Socket A.

Comment: Those IPv4 multicast addresses are local to the link and are reserved. 224.0.0.2 is the "All Routers on this Subnet", and 224.0.0.3 is "Unassigned". What happens with 224.0.0.3 is undefined. You don't mention which IPv6 multicast addresses you are using.

Comment: The IPs are an example. I've proved with 239.255.251.100 and 239.255.221.101 and obtain same behaviour.
When I do the joinGroup, I always pass an IPv4 Multicast. Is at runtime, when java invokes the implementation of ipv6 or ipv4.
You can try it.

Comment: You still didn't list the IPv6 multicast addresses you are using. IPv6 has many different types of multicast addresses with flags built into the addresses that change the behavior of the multicast.